# Why is my R code visible in Quarto Output despite echo: false

Tags: r, pdf-generation, quarto

PDF-Output
[image]
Code used:
[image]

The code should not be displayed, only the output.

I tried with different combinations of
`#| eval: true #| echo: false #| output: true`
etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the empty line between `r` and `#| echo: false`. Consider this simple example to see the difference:

````
---
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
head(mtcars)
```


```{r}

#| echo: false

head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Quarto expects the chunk options directly underneath after the definition of the type of code chunk (`{r}` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it matters if there is an empty line between the two lines in the red box.
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxLeY.png]

As soon as the empty line from the initial question above is removed, the code chunk is processed properly in the output and shows no more code.
**[image: strong text]**

I hope this saves somebody some time that is struggling with the same problem.